# Android merge two images

Tags: android, image, merge, android-canvas

I want to merge two images and then save them on the Android SDCard.One is from the camera and one from the resources folder. The problem is that i get this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor. Thanks.

```
        Bitmap bottomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.blink);
        Bitmap topImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  

        // As described by Steve Pomeroy in a previous comment, 
        // use the canvas to combine them.
        // Start with the first in the constructor..
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bottomImage);
        // Then draw the second on top of that
        comboImage.drawBitmap(topImage, 0f, 0f, null);

        // bottomImage is now a composite of the two. 

        // To write the file out to the SDCard:
        OutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + "myNewFileName.png");
            bottomImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);

            //Bitmap image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v("error saving","error saving");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Managed to fix it by simply doing this change:

```
        int w = bottomImage.getWidth();
        int h = bottomImage.getHeight(); 
        Bitmap new_image = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h ,bottomImage.getConfig());
```

The problem now is that it doesn't saves the image. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_modify_the_image_file-t513.html) will help you =)

---

**Edit:** (embed answer from link)

the only static "constructor" for Bitmap returning a mutable one is:

> (Class: Bitmap) public static Bitmap createBitmap(int width, int
>   height, boolean hasAlpha)
>   Returns: a mutable bitmap with the specified width and height.

- So you could work with getPixels/setPixels or like this:

  ```
  Bitmap bitmapResult = bm.createBitmap(widthOfOld, heightOfOld, hasAlpha);
  Canvas c = new Canvas();
  c.setDevice(bitmapResult); // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
  c.drawBitmap(bitmapOld, left, top, paint);
  ```
- how to get the drawable from Bitmap: by using the BitmapDrawable-Subclass which extends Drawable, like this:

  ```
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decode(path);
  Drawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);
  ```

Comment: this will help, but more info on how would be better.

Comment: what I was trying to say is that your answer was flagged a possible spam because there was so little in the body, I looked at the link and seen it was relevant (and up-voted at that) but wanted to give you a heads up on it being flagged, I did not mean to imply it was wrong.

Comment: Well this is a bit slow procedure when one have to do this for every frame of video.
Is there any alternate method?

Answer (score 1):

The `bitmap` you are retrieving is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning it can't be modified. Although it doesn't specify on the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) page that the constructor needs a `mutable` bitmap, it does.

To create a `mutable` bitmap, you can use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29).