# How to combine multiple images into a single image in android?

Tags: android, image

I am working on a distributed application of android.I have splitted a single image into lets say 4 parts and then processed it. Now I want to combine 4 bitmap images into a single image. How can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944061/android-merge-two-images Hope this will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Bitmap[] parts = new Bitmap[4];
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(parts[0].getWidth() * 2, parts[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint();
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(parts[i], parts[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), parts[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
}
```

Something like this =)

Answer (score 7):

Following piece of code will do the trick for you to combine four bitmaps in one.
Call this method 3 times to combine the four images.

Step 1:Combine first two images

Step 2:Combine the renaming two images

Step 3:Combine the the two new created bitmaps

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```