# I want to save my gridview in one imageview

Tags: android, gridview, filesystems, android-sdcard

How to save my grid full grid view items in one image view someone help me. In below code this is my ImageAdapter for grid view and here is bit is my gridview item and **i want to save "mthum" bitmap array in my sdcard in image view**

```
            public  class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;
            Bitmap bit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(S.Murge_Bitmap, 280,  280, false);
            public Bitmap[] mThum={bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit,bit};
            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
            return mThum.length;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThum[position];
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
            }


            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {   
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mThum[position]);
            return imageView;
            }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this solution, but I think it's gonna give you only a Bitmap of displayed images :

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGridView.getDrawingCache());
```

if you have an issue with this and can't get a bitmap, try this :

```
mGridView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
// Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
mGridView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
mGridView.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()); 

mGridView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGridView.getDrawingCache());
mGridView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

otherwise, if you want all your images from your "Adapter" you can construct you Bitmap like describe in this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15152221/1686472

**EDIT :** I didn't see you wanted to save the image on SD card, there is plenty of answer about that so you should take a look at them :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662384/1686472

Comment: this is running i used this code in my activity thanks

Comment: Please mark it as answered. Check the mark at the top left of my answer.

Comment: it gave me error NullPointerException at line Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(gridview.getDrawingCache());

Comment: Well you can check that your gridview != null && gridview.getDrawingCache() != null . But you won't have your bitmap. You need to call this method after the gridview is rendered.

Comment: Thanks its working but i want to convert whole gridview images in one bitmap not only visible portion. Is it possible?