# How to arrange multiple images to a quadview image

Tags: android, image

I have an Android app taking 4 pictures.
I want to arrange these images to one image as quadview.

So the final image contains basically 4 pictures

pic1 pic2

pic3 pic4

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a layout like this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to have at the end one new image which contains all 4 images and can be send to facebook.

Comment: @tobias then you should look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151937/how-to-combine-multiple-images-into-a-single-image-in-android)